# Program not responding while connecting to SQL Server

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I'm writing window form application in c#.net and connect to SQL Server on Local Network.
if network disconnected my program is not responding. I mean it tries to select data from sql server but network is disconnected. How to catch this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a try-catch block in your program?  What is the timeout you've set when trying to connect?

Comment: Yes I use try catch! But I don't know how to set timeout! If you know plz answer! Thank you big big

Comment: Can you show the code you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  basically need to check for the Open Connection First!

```
SqlConnection  con = new SqlConnection(Connection_string); //specify your connection string such as Server database etc ...
if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
 //statements
```

And you can make an event to Notify that the connection has been closed !

Comment: Thanks you so much! I din't check connection before I select data! I'll try it

Comment: @Mean Sokleap accept  the answer  if you like the answer =)

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation for timing out [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here's their example code

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
/// 
public class A {
   /// 
   public static void Main() {
      string connectionString = "";
      // Wait for 5 second delay in the command
      string queryString = "waitfor delay '00:00:05'";
      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
         connection.Open();
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
         // Setting command timeout to 1 second
         command.CommandTimeout = 1;
         try {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         catch (SqlException e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Got expected SqlException due to command timeout ");
            Console.WriteLine(e);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Notice the line

```
command.CommandTimeout = 1;
```

Definitely wrap your sql code under the 'using' too, as it will deallocate resources automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks you! I'll try it.